# Change URL but stay on the same page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a URL:

www.example.com/property-listings/united-states/colorado/denver/denver-co-office-space

I want to stay on the same page above but simply display the URL in the address bar like this:

www.example.com/property-listings/united-states/colorado/denver/office-space

How do I accomplish this using htaccess and rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, try writing a rule like this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule property-listings/united-states/colorado/denver/office-space  http://www.example.com/property-listings/united-states/colorado/denver/denver-co-office-space [L]
```

OK. You didn't supply a pattern or mentioned there was any, so I have to guess the pattern is up to /denver/ subdirectory. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(property-listings/united-states/colorado/denver/)(office-space)/?$  $1denver-co-$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(property-listings/united-states/colorado)/(denver)/(office-space)/?$ $1/$2/$2-co-$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Tried the above code however it doesn't seem that the rewrite rule is being executed. I know I have mod_rewrite enabled, because when I add random garbage to my .htaccess I get an 500 error. What could be causing the rewrite rule not to work?